# django: How to create Terms of Agreement

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-middleware

I am working with a site which is already connected to single sign on system. Now I want to add terms of agreement page. Here is the flow that I am thinking of:

If I have a record of the user who is logging in that means the user has already seen it so we no longer need to show the agreement page. But if the record doesn't exist in the table I want to redirect to a view that has terms of agreement and user can go further on the sign in process only upon acceptance. If fail to accept we show the non-signed on version of the site.

Since its a single sign on system I have created a table on my end to just keep track of the users who login-to the site. And this is the table I should look up for record.

Here is how I create the record when they sign in: 
This is in the my middleware class

```
shib_umnPersonType = shib_meta.get('uPersonType','')
shib_uRole = shib_umnPersonType.strip().split(';')[0]
#raise(shib_meta)
try:
    shib_user = ShibUser.objects.get(shib_username=username)
    user = shib_user.auth_user
    user.backend = "django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend"
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    user = auth.authenticate(remote_user=username)
    user.shibuser_set.create(shib_username=username, shib_user_role=shib_uRole)
```

What I am thinking at this point is I should interrupt the request in the except: But I am not really sure if thats that the way it should be done. I am also not a experience django developer.

If thats the way to do it then I guess I should be calling a view with a form from that location then check the response ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with view decorator.

If you detect in decorator, that user has not agreed to recent Terms, then redirect it to Terms page with extra parameter passed on to that view. Pick that parameter up in the Terms view and based on that paramter redirect user to previous view if user accepted the Terms.